# Apollo link state setup?

Tags: apollo

Im trying to set up Apollo link state following the docs: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link-state

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import { HttpLink, InMemoryCache, ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client-preset';
    import { WebSocketLink } from 'apollo-link-ws';
    import { ApolloLink, split } from 'apollo-link';
    import { getMainDefinition } from 'apollo-utilities';
    import { AUTH_TOKEN } from './constant';
    import RootContainer from './components/RootContainer';
    import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';

    const httpLink = new HttpLink({ uri: 'http://localhost:4000' });

    const middlewareLink = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
ation token from local storage if it exists
      const tokenValue = localStorage.getItem(AUTH_TOKEN);
      operation.setContext({
        headers: {
          Authorization: tokenValue ? `Bearer ${tokenValue}` : '',
        },
      });
      return forward(operation);
    });

    const httpLinkAuth = middlewareLink.concat(httpLink);

    const wsLink = new WebSocketLink({
      uri: `ws://localhost:4000`,
      options: {
        reconnect: true,
        connectionParams: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem(AUTH_TOKEN)}`,
        },
      },
    });

    const link = split(
      ({ query }) => {
        const { kind, operation } = getMainDefinition(query);
        return kind === 'OperationDefinition' && operation === 'subscription';
      },
      wsLink,
      httpLinkAuth,
    );

    const client = new ApolloClient({
      clientState: {
        defaults: {
          isConnected: true,
        },
        resolvers: {
          Mutation: {
            updateNetworkStatus: (_, { isConnected }, { cache }) => {
              cache.writeData({ data: { isConnected } });
              return null;
            },
          },
        },
      },

      link: ApolloLink.from([link]),

      cache: new InMemoryCache(),

      connectToDevTools: true,
    });

    const token = localStorage.getItem(AUTH_TOKEN);

    ReactDOM.render(
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <RootContainer token={token} />
      </ApolloProvider>,
      document.getElementById('root'),
    );
```

When I try a query:

```
{
  networkStatus @client {
    isConnected
  }
}
```

I get this error

```
    {
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Response not successful: Received status code 400",
      "locations": [
        "Error: Response not successful: Received status code 400\n    at throwServerError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:5296:17)\n    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:5321:13"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

UPDATED CODE: I'm no longer getting errors but the query returned is always an empty object.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { HttpLink, InMemoryCache, ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client-preset';
import { WebSocketLink } from 'apollo-link-ws';
import { ApolloLink, split } from 'apollo-link';
import { getMainDefinition } from 'apollo-utilities';
import { AUTH_TOKEN } from './constant';
import RootContainer from './components/RootContainer';
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';
import { withClientState } from 'apollo-link-state';
import { gql } from 'apollo-boost';

const httpLink = new HttpLink({ uri: 'http://localhost:4000' });

const middlewareLink = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  // get the authentication token from local storage if it exists
  const tokenValue = localStorage.getItem(AUTH_TOKEN);
  // return the headers to the context so httpLink can read them
  operation.setContext({
    headers: {
      Authorization: tokenValue ? `Bearer ${tokenValue}` : '',
    },
  });
  return forward(operation);
});

// authenticated httplink
const httpLinkAuth = middlewareLink.concat(httpLink);

const wsLink = new WebSocketLink({
  uri: `ws://localhost:4000`,
  options: {
    reconnect: true,
    connectionParams: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem(AUTH_TOKEN)}`,
    },
  },
});

const link = split(
  // split based on operation type
  ({ query }) => {
    const { kind, operation } = getMainDefinition(query);
    return kind === 'OperationDefinition' && operation === 'subscription';
  },
  wsLink,
  httpLinkAuth,
);

const cache = new InMemoryCache();

const stateLink = withClientState({
  cache,
  resolvers: {
    Query: {
      networkStatus: (_, args, { cache }) => {
        return cache.readQuery({
          query: gql`
            query {
              networkStatus @client {
                isConnected
              }
            }
          `,
        });
      },
    },
    Mutation: {
      updateNetworkStatus: (_, { isConnected }, { cache }) => {
        const data = {
          networkStatus: {
            __typename: 'NetworkStatus',
            isConnected,
          },
        };
        cache.writeData({ data });
        return null;
      },
    },
  },
  defaults: {
    networkStatus: {
      __typename: 'NetworkStatus',
      isConnected: true,
    },
  },
});

// apollo client setup
const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: ApolloLink.from([stateLink, link]),
  cache,
  connectToDevTools: true,
});

const token = localStorage.getItem(AUTH_TOKEN);

ReactDOM.render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <RootContainer token={token} />
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

If I remove defaults then the query isn't recognised. So I think im either writing or reading from the store incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't actually configured the state link. The sample configuration from the docs:

```
import { withClientState } from 'apollo-link-state';

// This is the same cache you pass into new ApolloClient
const cache = new InMemoryCache(...);

const stateLink = withClientState({
  cache,
  resolvers: {
    Mutation: {
      updateNetworkStatus: (_, { isConnected }, { cache }) => {
        const data = {
          networkStatus: {
            __typename: 'NetworkStatus',
            isConnected
          },
        };
        cache.writeData({ data });
        return null
      },
    },
  }
});
```

You then have to include it in your client configuration:

```
link: ApolloLink.from([stateLink, link])
```

Comment: Ive updated my question. Have I written my query incorrectly?

Comment: Your query resolver is just hitting the cache and effectively asking for itself. Try returning `true` or `false` inside the resolver, or do something like `window.navigator.onLine`

Comment: Ah I thought the gql query would be run.

Comment: For these resolvers, you must return some kind of data, just like you would on the server side. You can interact with the cache, but at the end of day, you need to return some kind concrete value. I believe for queries, you can also omit the resolver altogether as long as you have a default set.